# How to determine which items in one List are not in other List?

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio-2005, set

If I have:

```
List<String> list1  AND  List<String> list2
```

What is the best way to generate a `List<String>` that contains the items in `list1` that are not in `list2`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using linQ, more about Except [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx)

```
var res = list1.Except(list2);
```

Doing this without linQ

```
List<string> listExcept = new List<string>();
foreach(string list1Item in list1)
{
   if(!list2.Contains(list1Item))
      listExcept.Add(list1Item);
}   
//here listExcept will contain all the elements present in list1 and not present in list2
```

Comment: This (after edit) is a natural solution if you can use LINQ (new in .NET 3.5) and have implicitly typed local variables (`var` keyword new in C# 3). But if the Original Poster needs to do this is Visual Studio 2005, he won't succeed.

Answer (score 1):

If you really only have the BCL of .NET 2.0, and the language features of C# 2, then you can't use extension methods, LINQ, `HashSet<>` and stuff like that. You would probably say:

```
List<string> resultList = new List<string>();
foreach (string s in list1)
{
  if (!list2.Contains(s))
    resultList.Add(s);
}
```

It will not perform too well. If that's important, maybe first create a `Dictionary<,>` based on `list2`.

Comment: @GaryJones In the above code, every time there's one element `s` in `list1`, the code will have to run through (potentially) all elements in `list2` to see if `s` is in `list2` as well. If there are `n_1` elements int `list1`, and `n_2` elements in `list2`, it will take a time of `n_1 * n_2` to finish. In some situations it may be faster to first copy the elements of `list2` to a collection where it's fast to check if `s` is present or not. But if the lists are not very huge, or the operation is not performed extremely often, then you don't have to care about all this.